# Button Submit false works, but not the redirecting

Tags: php, html, submit, forward, redirect

Currently, I am working on a formula. I created the check function and they are all working. If the check function returns false nothing gets saved, but it still redirects to the congrats page?

here the code:

```
function check() {
    var msg = "";

    if ($_POST['Bustransfer'] == "ja" ) {
        msg = "wrong\n";
        document.formular.v6.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    } 

    if (msg == "") return(true);
    else {
        alert(msg);
        return(false);
    }
}
```

and then I got the following in the body section:

```
<form method="post" action="Email.php" name="formular" onsubmit="return check()">
```

I don't get it, hope you can help me. Cheers!

Comment: You should show the input elements too.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing them(`javascript` & `php`) up. Should be `'<?php echo $_POST['Bustransfer']; ?>'` instead of `$_POST['Bustransfer']` in the check.

```
function check() {
    var msg = "";

    if ('<?php echo $_POST['Bustransfer']; ?>' == "ja" ) {
        msg = "wrong\n";
        document.formular.v6.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    } 

    if (msg == "") return(true);
    else {
        alert(msg);
        return(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: just one more thing, I want to get an error if the bustransfer got not 'ja' AND if the checkbox is unchecked

so  the radio button bustransfer, value ja and the checkbox v6 

`code` if ('<?php echo $_POST['Bustransfer']; ?>' == "ja" && <?php !isset($_POST['v6']) ?> ) {
 msg = "bla bla\n";
} 
`code`
what is wrong with the code?

Comment: `echo isset($_POST['v6'])`

Comment: it still doenst alert at this specific if-loop